daemon-reload behavior in systemd's ExecStartPre
I have a unit file myservice.service that looks like this:
...
ExecStartPre=prehook.sh
...
ExecStart=myapp
ExecStopPost=posthook.sh
...

prehook.sh performs various things, and, among the others, it replaces the unit file if it differs from a local copy and invokes daemon-reload:
...
# Compare files
if cmp -s "$SYSTEMD_FILE" "$LOCAL_FILE"; then
  echo "Unit files are identical. No update required."
else
  echo "Unit files differ. Updating systemd unit file."
  
  # Copy local version to /lib/systemd/system
  cp "$LOCAL_FILE" "$SYSTEMD_FILE"
  systemctl daemon-reload
  
  echo "Systemd configuration reloaded"
fi

#continue with something else
...

The local copy differs from the currently loaded unit file in the ExecStart line:
...
ExecStart=myappModified
...

The behavior I would expect is that, if unit file is changed during ExecStartPre, daemon-reload affects only subsequent invocations of systemctl start myservice, not the current one.
Surprisingly, systemd seems to reload "on the fly" the ExecStart line, honoring what is indicated in the local copy.
While this is a convenient behavior for the prehook script, I cannot find any evidence of this in the documentation. Am I overlooking something?
Systemd version is 240.
